# javascript parseInt on php

Tags: javascript, php, int, parseint

Simply I need this function on PHP:

```
parseInt('0x0' + 'e');
```

It returns 14.

```
parseInt('0x0' + 'b');
```

It returns 11.

THIS IS A JAVASCIPT. NOW I WANT TO DO IT ON PHP.
I tried this but not returned 11 or 14.

```
$a[] = intval('0x0' . '14');
```

Comment: So what did it return? And why did you replace 'e' and 'b' with '14'?

Comment: And why the caps?

Answer (score 0):

I got it from this link: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21596911/ParseInt-function-for-PHP.html

I need to make my code like this:

```
intval(substr('e',0,8),16); // returns 14
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need, remove quotes from 0x or hex numbers

```
echo intval(0xe);
// => 14
```